# `Packages not available in repository and won't be installed` when use `checkpoint()` to install packages from MRAN

Tags: r, microsoft-r, rro

I used R 3.5.3 with Rstudio 1.1.463,and `install.package()` from `CRAN` before.

Today I tried `checkpoint("2019-12-11",R.version = "3.5.3", verbose = TRUE)` but lots of packages not installed well as below:

```
> library(checkpoint)

checkpoint: Part of the Reproducible R Toolkit from Microsoft
https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility/
> checkpoint("2019-12-11",R.version = "3.5.3", verbose = TRUE)
Scanning for packages used in this project
The knitr package is not available and Rmarkdown files will not be parsed
  |======================================================================| 100%
- Discovered 289 packages
Unable to parse 16 files:
- R/win-library/3.5/checkpoint/examples/example_checkpoint.R
- R/win-library/3.5/checkpoint/examples/example_mranurl.R
- R/win-library/3.5/checkpoint/examples/example_remove.R
- R/win-library/3.5/checkpoint/examples/example_setSnapshot.R
- R/win-library/3.5/EnvStats/scripts/Manual/Chapter06.R
- R/win-library/3.5/ggthemes/examples/ex-calc_shape_pal.R
- R/win-library/3.5/ggthemes/examples/ex-few_shape_pal.R
- R/win-library/3.5/ggthemes/examples/ex-palette_pander.R
- R/win-library/3.5/ggthemes/examples/ex-tableau_shape_pal.R
- R/win-library/3.5/ggthemes/examples/ex-theme_economist.R
- R/win-library/3.5/htmlTable/examples/data-SCB_example.R
- R/win-library/3.5/MASS/scripts/ch16.R
- R/win-library/3.5/rex/doc/url_parsing.R
- R/win-library/3.5/rockchalk/examples/plot-Normal-2-clt.R
- R/win-library/3.5/rockchalk/examples/plot-Normal-3-plotmath.R
- R/win-library/3.5/stringr/doc/regular-expressions.R
Packages not available in repository and won't be installed:
 - async
 - countreg
 - emx
 - GLMMGibbs
 - gWidgetsWWW2
 - lme4.0
 - mvtnormAPI
 - Sxslt
 - testRcppClass
 - testRcppInterfaceExporter
 - testRcppInterfaceUser
 - testRcppModule
 - tree
 - yags
Installing packages used in this project
 - Installing 'actuar'
actuar
 - Installing 'AER'
AER
```

You can find several packages not well installed `Packages not available in repository and won't be installed`, such as `async,countreg,emx,GLMMGibbs,gWidgetsWWW2,lme4.0,mvtnormAPI,Sxslt,testRcppClass,testRcppInterfaceExporter,testRcppInterfaceUser,testRcppModule,tree,yags`.

I think MRAN include all CRAN packages,but not.
For example,I search https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/packages ,there's no package named `tree`,but I can find this package in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/

I raise questions:
1.Does MRAN include all CRAN packages start at year 2019?
2.How to install `not available in repository and won't be installed` packages  through `checkpoint`?

Comment: You can always also install from CRAN. Just be aware of versioning.

Comment: if you reinstalled R and RStudio and the problem went away you should probably delete the question ...